# Problem using wxRuby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, path, rubygems, wxruby

I am trying to create my first GUI using wxRuby. I installed wxRuby (using `gem install wxruby-ruby19`) and, it seemed to be installed alright. I copied some code directly from the wxRuby site. Here is the code I used:

*test.rb*

```
require "wx"
include Wx

class MinimalApp < App
  def on_init
    Frame.new(nil, -1, "The Bare Minimum").show()
  end
end

MinimalApp.new.main_loop
```

When I ran it, I got this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-ruby19-2.0.1-x86-linux/lib/wxruby2.so (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-ruby19-2.0.1-x86-linux/lib/wx.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I thought it was saying that wxruby wasn't in that directory, but I checked and it was, so I'm not sure what the problem is. If anyone could help, that would be awesome.

Comment: there is a wxruby2.so, but yeah, there is no libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0, I'll see if I can download that.

Comment: I agree with mu. Maybe, you should have done `sudo gem install`, not just `gem install`.

Comment: i dont think i have gtk+ installed, or wxwidgets...could that be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use wxRuby you need wxWidgets installed (wxGTK in your case).
The problem is wxRuby uses the wxWidgets shared libraries (e.g. libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0) and it cant find them.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same thing and got the same result.

It turns out that there are 2 wxRuby gems. If you are using Ruby 1.9x, you want wxRuby-ruby19. (gem install wxruby-ruby19).

I uninstalled the wxruby gem that I installed the first time (gem uninstall wxruby), and then installed the gem for my version of Ruby (gem install wxruby-ruby19). And Voila! All the sample code just worked. No additional downloads needed.